# Strategy or tool to manage & organise multiple BigQuery scripts

Tags: google-bigquery

We have 50 plus relevant BigQuery scripts stored under 'Saved Queries'. There doesn't seem to be an option to store these scripts in a hierarchy of folders. Am I missing something or is there some way of managing & organising BigQuery scripts, which becomes more and more complex when sharing across increasing numbers of analysts?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `BigQuery`'s saved queries can't be organized in a hierarchy of folders or something similar. If you think such feature could help you and others in the future, feel free to create a feature request in the proper [GCP channel](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685).

At the moment to manage the access to your saved queries you need to manage the **IAM** roles for the users in your project as you can find in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries#sharing_a_saved_query)

> **Project-level saved queries:** 
> **Creating** a project-level saved query
> requires bigquery.savedqueries.create permissions. The bigquery.admin
> predefined role includes bigquery.savedqueries.create permissions.
> **Viewing** a project-level saved query requires bigquery.savedqueries.get
> and bigquery.savedqueries.list permissions. The bigquery.admin and
> bigquery.user predefined roles include bigquery.savedqueries.get and
> bigquery.savedqueries.list permissions.
> **Updating** a project-level saved
> query requires bigquery.savedqueries.update permissions. The
> bigquery.admin predefined role includes bigquery.savedqueries.update
> permissions. 
> **Deleting** a project-level saved query requires
> bigquery.savedqueries.delete permissions. The bigquery.admin
> predefined role includes bigquery.savedqueries.delete permissions.

An approach that might help you is using **Google Groups** to define different groups of users that need different permissions. In this approach you can give permissions to the groups you have and when a new user is created you just need to add it to the more convenient group. You can find more information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_group)